# How do I get one class method to be different for each child (and call it from base class)

Tags: python, django

With an instance of Concert I get: unbound method do_stuff() must be called with Concert instance as first argument (got ModelBase instance instead)

models.py:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    def do_stuff(self):
        response self.do_specific_stuff(self)


class Concert(Event):
    def do_specific_stuff(self):
        ...

class Party(Event):
    def do_specific_stuff(self):
        ...
```

views:

```
def index(request):
    x = Concert.objects.get(name='Jack White @ Oakland')
    output = x.do_stuff()
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

**My goal is to loop trough all the events and execute the do_specific_stuff child class method based on what kind of event it is.**

Comment: Your class Event has no method do_specific_stuff(), and  if it had, you dont need to pass self to it.

Comment: Which class does `Event.objects.get(name='Jack White @ Oakland')` return an instance of?

Comment: I know but my question is can I call the subclass method do_specific_stuff (of the concert in this example) trough the base class in views.py?

Comment: @Vaughn an instance of the Event class

Comment: @Dieter: The Event class doesn't have do_specific_stuff.  You will need to get either a Concert or Party instance.

Comment: I tried it with a concert I added the error above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Django, inheritance triggers multi-table inheritance, but you don't get the polymorphism in Python.  It's just an instance of the ORM not providing a perfect correspondence between the data schema and the object model.

In other words, when you query Event, you get back a whole bunch of Event objects, regardless of whether some of them are actually Concert or Party objects.  You have to manually downcast.  If an Event is a Concert, it will have an attribute called `concert`, which points to the corresponding Concert subclass.  Likewise for Party.  If it is just a normal Event, it will have neither attribute.

You could use the following property on Event to automatically downcast your object:

```
@property
def as_child_class(self):
    """Casts this object to its subclass, if possible"""

    if hasattr(self, 'concert'):
        return self.concert
    elif hasattr(self, 'party'):
        return self.party
    else:
        return self
```

Then you could do something like:

```
for event in Event.objects.all()
    event.as_child_class.do_specific_stuff()
```

Similar questions have come up before:

- [Polymorphism in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397537/polymorphism-in-django)
- [How do I access the child classes of an object in django without knowing the name of the child class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929029/how-do-i-access-the-child-classes-of-an-object-in-django-without-knowing-the-nam/929982#929982)

And this link has some other ideas:

- http://jeffelmore.org/2010/11/11/automatic-downcasting-of-inherited-models-in-django/

Comment: That makes sense! How do I use this? Let me try that!

Comment: Only if you're calling it on Event objects would you want to do `self.as_child_class.do_specific_stuff()`.  You don't need to manually pass self to any of the functions, and because `as_child_class` is a property, you can treat it like you're retrieving a member variable.  Check my edit out, for code you might call from a view.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your `Event` model is **ONLY** for inheritance, so you should abstract it:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        absract = True

    def do_stuff(self):
        response self.do_specific_stuff()

    def do_specific_stuff(self):
        raise NotImplemented


class Concert(Event):
    def do_specific_stuff(self):
        ...


class Party(Event):
    def do_specific_stuff(self):
        ...
```

I may be wrong about your usage of `Event`, but if it was, abstracting your `Event` model will have it to be like a plain class, I mean no database actions will be taken for such model.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, see [Template method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern/%22Template%20Method%20pattern%22)

Secondly, the Event class should be abstract.

```
class Event:
   def __init__:
       raise NotImplemented('This class is abstract')
```

Thirdly, see [Single Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html%22Single%20table%22) and [Class Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html%22Class%20Table%20Inheritance%22) patterns.
And django-ORM realisation of the patterns [there](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes)
Good luck =)