# Should I avoid multi-table (concrete) inheritance in Django by any means?

Tags: django, inheritance, models, multi-table-inheritance, concrete-inheritance

Many experienced developers recommend against using [Django multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) because of its poor performance:

1. [Django gotcha: concrete inheritance](http://jacobian.org/writing/concrete-inheritance/) by [Jacob Kaplan-Moss](http://jacobian.org/), a core contributor of Django.

   > In nearly every case, abstract inheritance is a better approach for
   >   the long term. I’ve seen more than few sites crushed under the load
   >   introduced by concrete inheritance, so I’d strongly suggest that
   >   Django users approach any use of concrete inheritance with a large
   >   dose of skepticism.
2. [Two Scoops of Django](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1481879707) by [Daniel Greenfield](http://pydanny.com/) ([@pydanny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/93270/pydanny))

   > Multi-table inheritance, sometimes called “concrete inheritance,” is
   >   considered by the authors and many other developers to be a bad thing.
   >   We strongly recommend against using it.
   >
   > At all costs, everyone should avoid multi-table inheritance
   >   since it adds both confusion and substantial overhead.
   >   Instead of multi-table inheritance, use explicit OneToOneFields and
   >   ForeignKeys between models so you can control when joins are
   >   traversed.

But without multi-table inheritance, I can't easily

1. [Reference base model in another model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23555478/django-onetoonefield-to-multiple-models) (have to use GenericForeignKey or reverse dependency);
2. [Get all instances of base model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729784/django-get-all-implementations-of-an-abstract-base-class).

   *(feel free to add more)*

So what is wrong with this kind of inheritance in Django? Why are explicit OneToOneFields better?

How much does performance suffer from JOINs? Are there any benchmarks that show the difference in performance?

<s>Does not `select_related()` allow us to control when JOINs are invoked?</s>

---

I have moved concrete examples to a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23555478/django-onetoonefield-to-multiple-models) since this one is becoming too broad, and added a list of reasons for using multi-table inheritance instead.

Comment: `What are the alternatives to multi-table inheritance when I need to reference a base class in another model?` Could you clarify what you mean by this?

Comment: Couple of simple examples would make the question clearer and would lead to better answers. Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe: I have added some examples that explain what I mean by referencing that base class in another model.

Comment: There are too many questions in one. I have moved a part of this question with code examples to a separate one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23555478/django-onetoonefield-to-multiple-models

Answer (score 34, accepted):

First of all, **inheritance has not a natural translation to relational database architecture** (ok, I know, Oracle Type Objects and some other RDBMS support inheritance but django don't  take advantage of this functionality)

At this point, notice than *django* generates new tables to subclasses and write **lots of `left joins`** to retrieve data from this *'sub-tables'*. And [left joins are not your friends](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2726683). In a high performance scenario, like a game backend or something else, you should avoid it and resolve inheritance 'by hand' with some artifacts like nulls, OneToOne or foreign keys. In `OneToOne` scenario, you can call the related table directly or only if you need it.

**... BUT ...**

*"In my opinion (TGW)"* **you should to include model inheritance in your enterprise projects when it catches to your [universe of discourse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_discourse)**. I do this, and I save a lot of development hours to my customers thanks to this feature. Also, **code becomes clean and elegant** and that means easy maintenance (notice that this kind of projects don't have hundreds or requests by second)

**Question by question**

Q: What is wrong with this kind of inheritance in Django? 
A: Lot of tables, a lot of left joins.

Q: Why are explicit OneToOneFields better? 
A: You can access directly to related model without left joins.

Q: Are there any illustrative examples (benchmarks)? 
A: No comparable.

Q: Does not select_related() allow us to control when JOINs are invoked? 
A: django joins needed tables.

Q: What are the alternatives to multi-table inheritance when I need to reference a base class in another model? 
A: Nullification. OneToOne relations and lots of code lines. It depends on application needs.

Q: Are GenericForeignKeys better in this case? 
A: Not for me.

Q: What if I need OneToOneField to base model? 
A: Write it. There is no problem with this. For example, you can extend User model, and also you can have a OneToOne to User base model for some users.

**Conclusion**

You should to know the cost of write and maintenance code without model inheritance also the cost of hardware to support model inheritance applications and act accordingly.

Just a joke: you can write it on assembly code, and it will run faster.

**Quoting [Trey Hunner](https://twitter.com/treyhunner/status/1441579713219031043?s=19)**:

> **Your time is usually much more expensive than your CPU's time.**

Comment: "Q: Why are explicit OneToOneFields better? 
A: You can access directly to related model without left joins." this is somewhat misleading. I think you need joins anyway. The difference is whether you do it explicitly or implicitly.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @eugene, you are right. Be free to improve answer. Thanks!

Comment: After 5 years from this answer, and reading the Django Docs, is it me or Django now created a one-to-one field automatically? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance

Answer (score 16):

### The world has changed.

The first thing to note is that the article titled [Django gotcha: concrete inheritance](https://jacobian.org/writing/concrete-inheritance/) was nearly four years old at the time this question was asked; in 2014. Both Django and RDBMs systems have come a long way since then (example mysql 5.0 or 5.1 were the widely used versions and 5.5 general availability was still one month away).

### Joins to my left, joins to my right

It is true that multi table inheritance does result in extra joins behind the scenes *most of the time*. But joins are not evil. It's worth noting that in a properly normalized database, you almost always have to join to fetch all the required data. When proper indexes are used, joins do not include any significant performance penalties.

### INNER JOIN vs LEFT OUTER JOIN

This is indeed the case against multi table inheritance, with other approaches it's possible to avoid a costly LEFT OUTER JOIN and do an INNER JOIN instead or perhaps a subquery. But with multi table inheritance you are denied that choice

Answer (score 15):

From what I understand, you are using `OneToOneField` on the `RelatedModel` to the `BaseModel` because ultimately, you want a one-to-one link between `RelatedModel` and each `Submodel1` to `Submodel9`. If so, there's a more efficient way of doing that without multi-table inheritance nor generic relations.

Just get rid of the `BaseModel` and in each `SubmodelX`, have a `OneToOneField` to `RelatedModel`

```
class Submodel1(models.Model):
    related_model = models.OneToOneField(RelatedModel, null=True, blank=True, related_name='the_thing')
    some_field = models.TextField()

# ...

class Submodel9(models.Model):
    related_model = models.OneToOneField(RelatedModel, null=True, blank=True, related_name='the_thing')
    another_field = models.TextField()
```

This would allow you to access `SubmodelX` from an instance of `RelatedModel` using a field named `the_thing`, just as in the multi-table inheritance example you first gave.

Note that you may use abstract inheritance to factor out the `related_model` field and any other common fields between `SubModel1` to `Submodel9`.

The reason using multi-table inheritance is inefficient is because it generates an extra table for the base model, and therefore extra JOINs to access those fields. Using generic relations would be more efficient if you later find that you instead need a `ForeignKey` field from `RelatedModel` to each `SubmodelX`. However, Django does not support generic relations in `select_related()` and you might have to end up building your own queries to do so efficiently. The tradeoff between performance and ease of coding is up to you depending on how much load you expect on the server and how much time you want to spend optimizing.

Comment: I have moved a part of my question with code examples and a part of your answer to a separate question. Don't you object? If you post an answer there, I will delete my own answer which references this one.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/23555565/517316

Comment: Does this still work? I thought 'related_name' must be unique.

Comment: @PawelKam you are correct.  You'd need to use something like `related_name='the_thing1'` instead.

Comment: How is your solution *more efficient than multi-table inheritance*?  See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58212278/10746224) to a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58209460/model-inheritance-benefits-of-explicit-onetoonefield-vs-implicit-multi-table-in/58212278) for a more detailed criticism of this.

Answer (score 8):

Whether the occurrence of `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is an issue in itself, I cannot say, but, in any case, it may be interesting to note **in which cases these outer joins actually occur**.

This is a naive attempt to illustrate the above, using some example queries.

Suppose we have some models using multi-table inheritance as follows:

```
from django.db import models

class Parent(models.Model):
    parent_field = models.CharField(max_length=10)


class ChildOne(Parent):
    child_one_field = models.CharField(max_length=10)


class ChildTwo(Parent):
    child_two_field = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

By default, the child instances get a `parent_ptr` and parent instances can access child objects (if they exist) using `childone` or `childtwo`. Note that `parent_ptr` represents a one-to-one relation which is used as the primary key (the actual child tables have no `id` column).

Here's a quick-and-dirty unit test with some naive `Django` query examples, showing the corresponding number of occurrences of `INNER JOIN` and `OUTER JOIN` in the `SQL`:

```
import re
from django.test import TestCase
from inheritance.models import (Parent, ChildOne, ChildTwo)

def count_joins(query, inner_outer):
    """ Count the occurrences of JOIN in the query """
    return len(re.findall('{} join'.format(inner_outer), str(query).lower()))


class TestMultiTableInheritance(TestCase):
    def test_queries(self):
        # get children (with parent info)
        query = ChildOne.objects.all().query
        self.assertEqual(1, count_joins(query, 'inner'))
        self.assertEqual(0, count_joins(query, 'outer'))
        # get parents
        query = Parent.objects.all().query
        self.assertEqual(0, count_joins(query, 'inner'))
        self.assertEqual(0, count_joins(query, 'outer'))
        # filter children by parent field
        query = ChildOne.objects.filter(parent_field=parent_value).query
        self.assertEqual(1, count_joins(query, 'inner'))
        self.assertEqual(0, count_joins(query, 'outer'))
        # filter parents by child field
        query = Parent.objects.filter(childone__child_one_field=child_value).query
        self.assertEqual(1, count_joins(query, 'inner'))
        self.assertEqual(0, count_joins(query, 'outer'))
        # get child field values via parent
        query = Parent.objects.values_list('childone__child_one_field').query
        self.assertEqual(0, count_joins(query, 'inner'))
        self.assertEqual(1, count_joins(query, 'outer'))
        # get multiple child field values via parent
        query = Parent.objects.values_list('childone__child_one_field',
                                           'childtwo__child_two_field').query
        self.assertEqual(0, count_joins(query, 'inner'))
        self.assertEqual(2, count_joins(query, 'outer'))
        # get child-two field value from child-one, through parent
        query = ChildOne.objects.values_list('parent_ptr__childtwo__child_two_field').query
        self.assertEqual(1, count_joins(query, 'inner'))
        self.assertEqual(1, count_joins(query, 'outer'))
        # get parent field value from parent, but through child
        query = Parent.objects.values_list('childone__parent_field').query
        self.assertEqual(0, count_joins(query, 'inner'))
        self.assertEqual(2, count_joins(query, 'outer'))
        # filter parents by parent field, but through child
        query = Parent.objects.filter(childone__parent_field=parent_value).query
        self.assertEqual(2, count_joins(query, 'inner'))
        self.assertEqual(0, count_joins(query, 'outer'))
```

Note, not all of these queries make sense: they are just for illustrative purposes.

Also note that this test code is not DRY, but that is on purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Django implements multi-table inheritance via an automatically-created OneToOneField as its docs says.So either use abstract inheritance or I don't think using an explicit OneToOneFields or ForeignKeys makes any differences.