# ForeignKeys clashing when using abstract multiple inheritance in Django

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-models

I am trying to set up a Django Model that works as a base class for other models. The Base model has two ForeignKey fields to other objects of the same class (TestForeign). I can get the models working using multitable inheritance but I want to use abstract model inheritance because I have read that there are some [performance issues when using multitable inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23466577/should-i-avoid-multi-table-concrete-inheritance-in-django-by-any-means).

The following example works when I use multitable inheritance (abstract = False) but fails when I run it with abstract inheritance.

```
class TestForeign(models.Model):
  test = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class BaseModel(models.Model):
  # specified related_name to avoid reverse accesor clash
  foo = models.ForeignKey(TestForeign, related_name='fooooo')
  bar = models.ForeignKey(TestForeign)

  class Meta:
    abstract = True

class AnotherModel(BaseModel):
  bla = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class YetAnotherModel(BaseModel):
  bla = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

When I synchronize the database I get the following error:

```
ERRORS:
Base.AnotherModel.bar: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'AnotherModel.bar' clashes with reverse accessor for 'YetAnotherModel.bar'.
HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'AnotherModel.bar' or 'YetAnotherModel.bar'.
Base.AnotherModel.bar: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'AnotherModel.bar' clashes with reverse query name for 'YetAnotherModel.bar'.
HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'AnotherModel.bar' or 'YetAnotherModel.bar'.
Base.AnotherModel.foo: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'AnotherModel.foo' clashes with reverse accessor for 'YetAnotherModel.foo'.
HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'AnotherModel.foo' or 'YetAnotherModel.foo'.
Base.AnotherModel.foo: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'AnotherModel.foo' clashes with reverse query name for 'YetAnotherModel.foo'.
HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'AnotherModel.foo' or 'YetAnotherModel.foo'.
Base.YetAnotherModel.bar: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'YetAnotherModel.bar' clashes with reverse accessor for 'AnotherModel.bar'.
HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'YetAnotherModel.bar' or 'AnotherModel.bar'.
Base.YetAnotherModel.bar: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'YetAnotherModel.bar' clashes with reverse query name for 'AnotherModel.bar'.
HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'YetAnotherModel.bar' or 'AnotherModel.bar'.
Base.YetAnotherModel.foo: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'YetAnotherModel.foo' clashes with reverse accessor for 'AnotherModel.foo'.
HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'YetAnotherModel.foo' or 'AnotherModel.foo'.
Base.YetAnotherModel.foo: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'YetAnotherModel.foo' clashes with reverse query name for 'AnotherModel.foo'.
HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'YetAnotherModel.foo' or 'AnotherModel.foo'.
```

Is there any way I can get the references of the base class not to clash in the derived models?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `%(class)s` and `%(app_label)s` in your related name, as specified in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#abstract-related-name).

Comment: E.G: foo = models.ForeignKey(TestForeign, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_foo")