# Django object composition with OneToOneField

Tags: python, django, orm

As noted in [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23466577/should-i-avoid-multi-table-concrete-inheritance-in-django-by-any-means), Django experts like *Two Scoops* recommend explicit [OneToOneFields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) rather than multi-table inheritance to avoid performance penalties of implicit joins.  I have tried to follow such an approach, and my design is actually object composition, but have a few questions. All three of these are concrete tables.

```
class Widget:
  ... many shared fields ...

class FunWidget:
  parent = models.OneToOneField(Widget, related_name='child', primary_key=True)
  ... fun-specific fields ...

class WorkWidget:
  parent = models.OneToOneField(Widget, related_name='child', primary_key=True)
  ... work-specific fields ...
```

My questions are:

1. *Related name*: Given a `Widget`, it'd be nice to refer to its related subtype with the same name, e.g., `Widget.child`. However, I get a `Reverse query name for ... clashes with reverse query name for ...` error. Therefore, it seems I must provide different `related_name`s, so that a given `Widget` would have either a `.funwidget` or a `.workwidget`.  To generalize I could provide a method `Widget.child()` which checks each of the possible `related_name`s, but that won't help me in queries.
2. *Filtering by Subtype*: Given a `QuerySet` of `Widget`, I need to filter to all which are of a given "subtype". I realize you'd normally just query the child model, but this is for a custom query set for `Widget` where I need to perform different filtering based on the type of "subclass". In other words, I want something like this `Widget.objects.filter(isinstance(child, WorkWidget))` which I realize isn't possible. Currently I am "duck typing" by checking for some different property of Widget (my dilemma from question 1 provides such a feature). Cleaner would be to store an explicit `.type` field, if I must.

I've failed to find a simple example with this kind of explicit one-to-one mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are right, the related names must differ.
2. Simply check for the existence of the given subtype:

   Widget.objects.select_related('workwidget').filter(workwidget__isnull=False)