# Polymorphic Model Inheritance in Django

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-models, sqlalchemy

This question is about model inheritance in Django.

Almost everything I have read (including the Django documentation itself) strongly recommends doing **'abstract base class'** inheritance rather than **'multi-table'** inheritance.
I agree with the reasoning and as a result am fully behind the recommendation. However, Django does not
appear to have support for:

- polymorphic querying, or
- model linking (i.e. I cannot create a ForeignKey field to the abstract base class from another model).

### Situation

For example, I have some models that implement the 'abstract base class' inheritance pattern:

```
class Tool(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    group = models.ManyToManyField(ToolGroup, blank=True) # Link to 'ToolGroup' MUST be placed on abstract class
    attributes = models.ManyToManyField(ToolAttributeValue, blank=True)  # Link to 'ToolAttributeValue' MUST be placed on abstract class

    class Meta:
        abstract = True # Almost everything I read strongly recommends against making this its own table


class HandheldTool(Tool):
    electrical_safe = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class PowerTool(Tool):
    compliance_expiry_date = models.DateTimeField()


class ConsumableTool(Tool):
    combustible = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    best_before = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

I also have some grouping and information classes related to tools in general:

```
# Grouping related structures
#
# ToolHierarchy  >       ToolGroup (n times)       > Tool
# 
#   "Tool Boxes" > "Day Shift"   > "Builders"      > HandheldTool[Hammer]
#                                                  > HandheldTool[Screwdriver - SAFE]
#                                                  > PowerTool[Drill]
#
#                                > "Demo Team"     > HandheldTool[Sledgehammer 1]
#                                                  > PowerTool[Jackhammer]
#                                                  > ConsumableTool[Dynamite]
#
#                > "Night Shift" > "Rock Breakers" > HandheldTool[Hammer]
#                                                  > HandheldTool[Sledgehammer 2]
#                                                  > PowerTool[Rocksaw]

class ToolHierarchy(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30)


class ToolGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='children', null=True, blank=True)
    hierarchy = models.ForeignKey(ToolHierarchy, null=True, blank=True, related_name='top_level_tools')
    # tools = models.ManyToManyField(Tool) # CANNOT MAKE LINK, as 'Tool' is abstract


# 'Extra-info' structures
#
# ToolAttribute > ToolAttributeValue > Tool
# 
#  'Brand'      > 'Stanley'          > HandheldTool[Hammer]
#                                    > HandheldTool[Sledgehammer 1]
#               > 'ACME'             > HandheldTool[Sledgehammer 2]
#                                    > ConsumableTool[Dynamite]
#
#  'Supplier'   > 'Bash Brothers'    > HandheldTool[Hammer]
#                                    > HandheldTool[Sledgehammer 1]
#                                    > HandheldTool[Sledgehammer 2]
class ToolAttribute(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    data_type = models.CharField(max_length=30) # e.g. "STRING", "INT", "DATE" "FLOAT" -- Actually done with enum
    unit_of_measure = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)


class ToolAttributeValue(models.Model):
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(ToolAttribute)
    value = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30)
    # tool = models.ForeignKey(Tool)  # CANNOT MAKE LINK, as 'Tool' is abstract
```

### Problem

Ideally this inheritance model would be implemented via a polymorphic relationship, however the Django ORM does not
support it. This is possible with SQLAlchemy and other ORMs like Hibernate.

With the Django ORM, because the `Tool` class is abstract I **cannot** create the links like:

- `ToolAttributeValue.tool -> tool_obj` or
- `ToolGroup.tools -> [tool_obj_1, tool_obj_2]`.

Instead I am forced to create the inverse link on the abstract class, despite it modelling a slightly different thing! This then results in all sorts of ugliness on the `ToolAttributeValue` and `ToolGroup` objects, which then no longer have a `.tools` attribute but instead have `RelatedManager` fields for each subtype. i.e.:

```
tool_group_obj.handheldtool_set.all()
tool_group_obj.powertool_set.all()
...etc, for every subtype of Tool
```

Which pretty much destroys the usefulness of the abstract class.

### Questions

So, with this in mind, my questions are:

1. Is this a good case for 'multi-table' inheritance?
2. Am I trying too hard to force the type inheritance? Should I just get rid of `Tool`? If yes, then do I have to create a `*ToolGroup` model for each subclass?
3. What is the current (Django 1.8) accepted way around this? Surely I am not the first person to build a relational system in Django ;-) And the fact that other ORMs have considered this problem suggest it is a common design choice.
4. Is the polymorphic solution (possibly via SQLAlchemy) an option? Is this being considered for Django 1.9+?

NB: I have read the docs for and tested https://github.com/chrisglass/django_polymorphic, but it does not appear to work
for 'abstract base class' inheritance (i.e. it is only for multi-table). If I did choose to do multi-table inheritance then
django-polymorphic would be good for the query side of my problem and I guess my model-linking problem would disappear.

NB: This is a similar question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23466577/should-i-avoid-multi-table-concrete-inheritance-in-django-by-any-means), but provides more detail.

Comment: Well, choose [your poison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database#answer-3579462). `abstract = True` avoids the base-table joins, but you also opt for not being able to have an in-db representation of the base model at all (meaning you can also not query the abstract models). `abstract = True` essentially means *don't realize this model, it's only a template*.

Comment: I guess that is my issue, I'm not sure which will be more poisonous. As far as 'less' poisonous options go, I am asking about if there is any accepted way to provide the Python-level abstraction over the concrete-table choice. Kind of like what is suggested here: [SLQAlchemy's declarative extention's union on concrete table inheritance](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/extensions/declarative/inheritance.html#concrete-table-inheritance). What do Django devs choose when presented with this problem?

Comment: I don't remember having ever read any "recommendation" against concrete inheritance in Django's doc ???  Now, while abstract inheritance + unions would probably be a fine thing it's not actually implemented in Django's ORM so your solutions are  mainly using concrete inheritance + django-polymorphic or implementing abstract inheritance + unions in Django's ORM.

Comment: If push comes to shove, you can always instruct polymorphic [not](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#non-polymorphic-queries) to do the subclass resolution. I have not tested it, but *union on concrete tables* should mean a big performance hit when you access common attributes (because you need to union over multiple tables instead of a simple join).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers  [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23466577/should-i-avoid-multi-table-concrete-inheritance-in-django-by-any-means) has some of the recommendations.

Comment: @Doddie these are not part of Django's official documentation are they ? But anyway: yes of course concrete inheritance doesn't come for free, and that should be obvious to anyone having any experience in relational databases. It doesn't mean you shouldn't use it when that's the right solution for the problem at hand.

Comment: Can you take a look at this https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managers.html and see if it solves your problem? I've been using it and works well.

Comment: @ShangWang Your link will help if I elect to go down the concrete inheritance path.

Comment: I posted a similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32500356/how-to-implement-variant-records-or-object-subclasses) a while ago. No answers. However, I mentioned a couple of other possibilities: using a single wide table with a lot of mostly blank or null fields, and if using Postgres and Django 1.8+, a table with an hstore field. Don't have anything to add to what's there, yet.

Comment: @nigel222 Yes, your question is pretty much the same. I will certainly look into the hstore option (I don't like the wide-table choice). I guess we are both waiting for someone with war stories to help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, so I think I'm going to answer my own questions...

1. **Is this a good case for 'multi-table' inheritance?**

   It appears so. Although there are a few places that recommend against 'multi-table' inheritance ([listed here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23466577/should-i-avoid-multi-table-concrete-inheritance-in-django-by-any-means)), some counterpoints are:

   - @Bruno Desthuilliers points out that these opinions are not from the 'official' documentation, and by extension, he implies that 'multi-table' is a perfectly good feature available for one to use.
   - My reading of @dhke's links and comments is that you *have* to choose one option, and that the 'multi-table' option is the only way databases truly support inheritance. I.e. Even with the polymorphic tricks of tools like Hibernate or SQLAlchemy, you are still choosing whether to JOIN tables ('multi-table' option) for object lookup or to UNION tables ('abstract base' / 'polymorphic' options) for set creation.
   - @dhke also points out that it is probably better to use the 'multi-table' option and tell a library like [django-polymorphic](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.org/) not to do subclass resolution when looking up the 'whole set' rather than have the database do a UNION over all of the tables (as would be required for 'whole set' lookup with the 'abstract base class' option).
2. **Am I trying too hard to force the type inheritance? Should I just get rid of `Tool`? If yes, then do I have to create a `*ToolGroup` model for each subclass?**

   No, it doesn't seem that way. The two uses of the `Tool` interface that I presented have different needs:

   - The `ToolGroup` / hierarchical-grouping use case is a good one for retaining the inherited `Tool` class. This would get very ugly if you had to create a type-specific set of classes for every type of tool
   - The `ToolAttribute` also makes a good case for the super class, except if you are able to use things like the HSTORE field type (provided by Postgres, I'm not sure about other backends). [This link](https://realpython.com/blog/python/fun-with-djangos-new-postgres-features/) gives a good rundown, and it is probably what I will do here (Thanks to @nigel222 for the research that went into the question!).
3. **What is the current (Django 1.8) accepted way around this? Surely I am not the first person to build a relational system in Django ;-) And the fact that other ORMs have considered this problem suggest it is a common design choice.**

   This is now an irrelevant question. Basically they don't worry about it.
4. **Is the polymorphic solution (possibly via SQLAlchemy) an option? Is this being considered for Django 1.9+?**

   Not that I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

The case that led me to this question is a model like this:

```
class PurchasableItem(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Cheesecake(PurchasableItem):
    pass


class Coffee(PurchasableItem):
    pass
```

The workaround I used is turning the parent class into an attribute:

```
class PurchasableItem(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        abstract = False


class Cheesecake(models.Model):
    purchasable_item = models.OneToOneField(PurchasableItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Coffee(models.Model):
    purchasable_item = models.OneToOneField(PurchasableItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This way, I can get both the behavior and querying functionality.

Comment: This is almost the same as concrete inheritance but at least you control the joins

Comment: This is a neat hack, not quite what I was asking about but a good idea nonetheless +1.