# Add Django model parent class to existing an existing model for multi-table inheritance

Tags: django, models, multi-table-inheritance

The [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) uses this example to demonstrate multi-table inheritance:

```
from django.db import models

class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)

class Restaurant(Place):
    serves_hot_dogs = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    serves_pizza = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

If I had initially built the Restaurant class like so:

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    serves_hot_dogs = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    serves_pizza = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

and then after a bunch of Restaurant objects have already been created, I realize it would have been better to use MTI, is there a good way to create the parent Place class after the fact and migrate the data?

Comment: Do you mean better in the means of code readability or performance? Maybe you should take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23466577/should-i-avoid-multi-table-concrete-inheritance-in-django-by-any-means

Comment: I am not very sure about you question, if you want to have parent model object and dont want to have table created for it you could use.

'class Meta:
      Abstract = True'

Comment: I mean I want to transition my current structure to use multi-table inheritance. For example, I'd like to now add an `Office` model which also has a name and address and I want all addresses to be unique; so I want to add the Place and the Office class and migrate my existing Restaurant data to use the new data structure.

Comment: @Amar: `abstract` must be written all-lowercase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Add the new models but keep the old one as well. **Make migrations**.
2. Write a **custom migration** to copy the data from the `Restaurant` model to the `NewRestaurant` model.
3. If necessary, change over any foreign key fields in other models from `Restaurant` to `NewRestaurant` and **make migrations**.
4. If necessary, change everywhere in the app that the `Restaurant` class is used to use the `NewRestaurant` class.
5. Delete the old restaurant model and **make migrations**.
6. Rename the new restaurant model to `Restaurant` so everything works again with the new structure. **Make migrations**.

Comment: I have a question - how do you keep the import of NewRestaurant in migration from p.2 if NewRestaurant later will be renamed?

Comment: @GriMel You do not make direct import to your app code from your migration, that is not maintenable for the reason you pinpointed, instead you would use `MyModel = apps.get_model('app','MyModel')`. Django will be able to run your code in its historical context, see more at https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.2/ref/migration-operations/#runpython

Answer (score 4):

Easy way: create fake `IntegerField` called `<parent_model>_ptr` in child model, populate it, and then remove it and add parent model at the same time.

Here is a complete article: http://www.johnborwick.com/blog/2013/08/using-south-to-change-a-django-models-parent-class/. It's about South, but the idea works with modern Django as well.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. I will be sure to try this the next time I run across this issue

Comment: Lifesaver! Thank you so much!