# Django – Migrate a field from a child model to its parent model – Manual migration for inheritance leads to a `FieldError`

Tags: django, django-migrations, django-inheritance

##### Short version

I'm trying to run a custom migration (via `RunPython`) that involves an inherited model, say `Restaurant`. However a `FieldError` exception is raised at `Restaurant.objects.all()`, specifying that an inherited field cannot be resolved. Indeed the model returned by `apps.get_model("myapp", "Restaurant")` oddly does not inherit from the parent class.

##### Longer version

###### Context

Consider a Django multi-table inheritance where a model, say `Restaurant(address, serves_pizza)`, inherits from a parent model, say `Place(name)`. The fields for both models are indicated between brackets. The goal is to transfer a certain `Restaurant` field, say `address`, to the parent class `Place`. One challenge is to preserve the data by transferring it through a customized migration operation. One idea that I feel is rather straightforward is

1. first create an intermediate field `address_place` in `Place`,
2. then, manually move the data from `Restaurant.address` to `Restaurant.address_place` (via `migrations.RunPython`)
3. finally remove `address` field and rename `address_place` into `address`

Focusing on 2., here is what the custom code called by `RunPython` looks like:

```py
def transfer_address_from_restaurant_to_place(apps, schema_editor):
    Restaurant = apps.get_model("myapp", "Restaurant")
    for restau in Restaurant.objects.all():
        restau.address_place = restau.address
        restau.save()
```

###### `FieldError`, the unexpected error

However when running the corresponding migration, a `FieldError` exception is raised at `for restau in Restaurant.objects.all()` and looks like:

```
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'name' into field. Choices are: address, serves_pizza
```

Yet `Restaurant` should have access to the fields of the parent class `Place`, that is `name` and `address_place`. In fact, if we examine the model `Restaurant` returned by `apps.get_model`, we can see that it does not inherit from the parent model `Place` at all, but simply from the base `models.Model`...

Hence

- what can explain this, namely that `apps.get_model` does not preserve the inheritance?
- and how to deal with it? or what other approach can be used to get around the problem and get the field `address` to the parent class?

---

##### Edit – how to reproduce the behavior

I think that this unexpected behavior comes from an older migration. A somewhat frustrating but workable solution would be to clean up the migration history as suggested by [@boyenec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14256643/boyenec).

First, I tried to reproduce the error on a minimal example. However everything worked fine: no `FieldError` was raised. By examining `Restaurant` from `apps.get_model("myapp", "Restaurant")`, it inherited  as expected from `Place`. In this minimal example I directly started from two models that looked like this:

```py
class Place(models.Model):
    name = ...

class Restaurant(Place):
    address = ...
    serves_pizza = ...
```

However this is not really representative of my migration history. Originally there was only `Restaurant(name, address, serves_pizza)`. And I created its parent class *a posteriori*, with a migration similar to this [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45307286/13410397). In this scenario the error I get is reproducible.

Comment: The error saying there is no fields `name` in your model you have `address, serves_pizza` fields in your model but there is no fields `name`. where you getting this error during run migration or search query from your function?

Comment: The error is raised when running the migration at `for restau in Restaurant.objects.all()`.  Note that there is no direct call to `Restaurant.name`. Nevertheless, since `Restaurant` inherits from `Place`, the attributes `address, serves_pizza, name` should be accessible. I'm thinking about a weird conflict that happens because of the fact that the `Restaurant` returned by `apps.get_model` does not inherit from `Place` ; when it should.

Comment: try to run migrations after delete your all migrations folders and file.

Comment: Indeed I'm starting to think that it comes from a previous migration

Comment: yeah try to run migrations after delete your all migrations folder and file  then if you are getting same problems then please add your resturent and place model in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and it was due to a `Meta.ordering` field on my model, which referenced a field that was transferred to the parent model.

In my `models.py`, I replaced:

```py
class Meta:
  ordering = ["name"]
```

By:

```py
class Meta:
  ordering = ["place_ptr__name"]
```

And created a migration for this change. After that my data migration ran without problems.