# Django combine different tables in separate table

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have 2 tables and wanted to `combine` 1st and 2nd table and show it in 3rd table

```
   class Date(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name

   class Month(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name
```

I have my 3rd table which is combination of 1st and 2nd table

I tried to use `models.ForeignKey(Date,Month)` in my 3rd table but only **Month table data** was shown in admin panel **Date table data** was not populated

My 3rd table looks like this

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Month,Date)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

I there any alternate way of populating data from different tables?

Any help is populating data of different tables in one table is very helpfull

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display objects from different models at the same page according to their published date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37747427/display-objects-from-different-models-at-the-same-page-according-to-their-publis)

Answer (score 2):

To get 1st and 2nd table content into 3rd table you need to write separate foreign keys for each model. We should not assign a single foreign key for both models.

```
class Group(models.Model):
    date = models.ForeignKey(Date)
    month = models.ForeignKey(Month)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.date.name) + str(seld.month.name)
```

The above code will return both Date and Month names.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this only gives value while querying in views. I wanted the data to be present in model (my 3rd table will have combination of PK of 2 tables as a drop down in admin panal)