# Design of multiple tables "e.g. Post and Comment" ordered by one column "date" in both tables

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-models

I use Postgres 9.6 and Django 1.10, but this may be more generic than the software packages I am using. However due to Django ORM limitations or/and my understanding, it may be dependent on these software packages.

My problem is I want to design Post and Comment tables. As easy as this seems, I will use heavily a query that fetches both `Posts` and `Comments`
ordered by date which is a timestamp in both tables so I can have something like post 1hour ago, post 2 hour ago, comment 3 hour ago, post 4 hour ago

Initial design can be like:

`Posts`:

```
`id`(serial primary key) | `author`(foreign key) | `title`(string) | `body`(string) | `created_on`(timestamp)
```

and `Comments`:

```
`id`(serial primary key) | post(foreign key to `Posts`) | `author`(foreign key) | `body`(string) | `created_on`(timestamp)
```

I don't know if it's feasible using native SQL or something like SQLAlchemy, but I think it is impossible to merge both `posts` and `comments` ordered by `created_on` of both tables.

I also looked into desiging posts and comments into something like this:

`Posts`

```
`id`(serial primary key) | `author`(foreign key) | `title`(string) | `created_on`(timestamp)
```

and `Comments`:

```
`id`(serial primary key) | post(foreign key to `Posts`) | `author`(foreign key) | `body`(string) | `created_on`(timestamp) | `is_op` (Boolean)
```

where `is_op` denotes whether it is the OP (i.e. post) or a comment to the post. This approach makes it easy to fetch both `posts` and `comments` since I have only one `created_on` column. However, this may cause penalty since I show posts much more frequently than comments yet I have to look into the `Comments` table every time I want to fetch the body of the `post`, also the `body` max length requirements are different for `posts` and `comments`. Also this approach makes it harder to fetch the count of the replies (i.e. number of comments  - 1 which is OP)using Django ORM.

How can I design these tables in a more efficient way that make it possible to get:

1. both comments and posts ordered by date.
2. annotate (according to Django naming convention) number of replies/likes for any post in one query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display objects from different models at the same page according to their published date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37747427/display-objects-from-different-models-at-the-same-page-according-to-their-publis)