# Django merge and sort queryset based on field (createdtstamp)

Tags: django, django-queryset, mergesort

I have three **django models** and I want to get CRUD logs. I have `merged` queryset and `sorted` them based on object creation date (createdtstamp field). I am using **[django-simple-history](https://github.com/treyhunner/django-simple-history)** stores Django model state on every create/update/delete.

```
player = Player.history.all().values('first_name','history_date', 'history_id', 'history_type', 'history_user_id', 'id', 'createdtstamp')
coach = Coach.history.all().values('coach_name','history_date', 'history_id', 'history_type', 'history_user_id', 'id', 'createdtstamp')
title = Title.history.all().values('title_name',  'history_date', 'history_id', 'history_type', 'history_user_id', 'id', 'createdtstamp')

#merge queryset and sort based on createdtstamp

result_list = sorted(chain(player, coach, title), key=lambda instance: instance.createdtstamp)

queryjson  = json.dumps(result_list, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)

return HttpResponse(queryjson)
```

**Above merge and sort doesn't seem to work!**

**How can I sort query result based on createdtstamp field (sort by latest)?**

Similar question have been asked before 
[Display objects from different models at the same page according to their published date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37747427/display-objects-from-different-models-at-the-same-page-according-to-their-publis)

But my question is different as `Player.history.select_related` doesn't have `Coach and Title` fields.

`Player.history.select_related('Coach', 'Title').all().order_by('-createdtstamp')`.

Comment: you can use Q objects for filtering.....for more details you can go here [Complex lookups with Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

Comment: It's not clear what your question is - your code already appears to merge and sort the querysets in the line `result_list = sorted(...)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display objects from different models at the same page according to their published date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37747427/display-objects-from-different-models-at-the-same-page-according-to-their-publis)

Comment: @e4c5 - I have createdtstamp on each model. I am trying to get CRUD logs of each models based on createdtstamp. Previous duplication link pointer was helpful though.