# Combining two queries from different application/models to display them on a single overview page

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have only recently started working with Django and was wondering how one would go around to combine two queries from different application/models and display them in a given overview page. I will display some non-functional pseudo-code below to illustrate what I am trying to do:

**Index.html**

Note that I added two seperate `context_object_names` here just to illustrate what I am trying to do (`latest_news` and `latest_enzyme`)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body %}

<div id="docs-content">
  <div class="section" id="s-module-django.db.models.fields">
    <div class="page-header text-primary">
      <h3 class="info-header-blue-publication-small">Overview</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3 class="info-header-blue-publication-tiny">Latest news:</h3>
    </div>
    {% if latest_news %}
      {{ latest_news.news_text }}
    {% else %}
      <p>No recent news.</p>
    {% endif %}

    <div>
      <h3 class="info-header-blue-publication-tiny">Latest enzyme:</h3>
    </div>
    {% if latest_enzyme %}
      <ul>
        <li><a href="{% url 'gts:detail' latest_enzyme.id %}">{{ latest_enzyme.barcode  }}</a></li>
      </ul>
    {% else %}
      <p>No enzymes are available.</p>
    {% endif %}

  </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

**Views.py**

Note that this contains some commented lines that illustrate the method that I was trying but did not get working, as well as two seperate `get_querysets` to illustrate my intent.

```
from django.shortcuts import render from django.http import
HttpResponse from django.views import generic

from gts.models import Enzymes 
from news.models import News

# Create your views here.

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'overview/index.html'

    #context_object_name = 'latest_enzyme_news'
    #def get_queryset(self):
    #    latest_enzyme = Enzymes.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[0]
    #    latest_news = News.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[0]
    #    return (latest_enzyme, latest_news)

    context_object_name = 'latest_enzyme'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Enzymes.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[0]

    context_object_name = 'latest_news'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return News.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[0]
```

I have looked at similar questions, where they tried to combine multiple queries from multiple models of the same application (*e.g.* [Display objects from different models at the same page according to their published date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37747427/1093485)) but I would appreciate any hint or tip on what would be the 'best practice' for the situation that I described as I would wish to combine queries from different applications more often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want a ListView here at all. You're not listing things; you're just getting two separate items.

Rather, use a standard TemplateView and define `get_context_data` to return the specific items you want.

```
class IndexView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'overview/index.html'

    def get_context_data(self):
        latest_enzyme = Enzymes.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[0]
        latest_news = News.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[0]
        return {'latest_enzyme': latest_enzyme, 'latest_news': latest_news}
```

(Note also, you could just as easily use a function-based view for this, since you are not really getting any value from the class.)

Comment: Thank you, that was a lot easier than I expected. I was just using a `ListView` everywhere but this shows me that I should spend a few days digging into the views.