# Django GenericForeignKey limit to ContentTypes that inherit from a particular abstract model

Tags: django, django-models

In my application's models I need a way of linking `Problems` and `Solutions` -- every `Problem` can have multiple `Solutions` and a given `Solution` can map back to multiple `Problems`.

`Solution` is an abstract base class, since there can be many varieties of `Solutions`.  So, I figured out I need a mapping table `ProblemSolutionMapping` which uses a `GenericForeignKey` to accommodate all those child classes.  But I'm trying to figure out how to limit the classes to just the children of `Solutions` and not all the classes available in the whole application, which is what is currently happening.

```
# Thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/a/23555691/1149759
class Solution(models.Model):
    ...
    @classmethod
    def get_subclasses(cls):
        content_types = ContentType.objects.filter(app_label=cls._meta.app_label)
        models = [ct.model_class() for ct in content_types]
        return [model for model in models
                if (model is not None and
                    issubclass(model, cls) and
                    model is not cls)]

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class ProblemSolutionMapping(models.Model):
    problem = models.ForeignKey(Problem)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,
        limit_choices_to=Solution.get_subclasses()) # <==== This is the issue
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

The issue is that when I start up my Django app, the call to `ContentType.objects.filter(app_label=cls._meta.app_label)` throws the error:

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

Not sure what to do -- I tried making the mapping table the last one in the relevant models file (all the child classes are defined above it in the same file), but it made no difference.  **Is this something that I have to move into the admin form?  Or is there some other way to do this at the model level?**

(Django 1.9, in case it matters.)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Refrecing to a model during import time is no longer supported from django 1.7. You should use your models after all application are loaded. So you should either **Staticly pass a list to your limit_choices_to** or **Use Q object** like this:

```
limit_choices_to=models.Q(app_label = 'app', model = 'a') | models.Q(app_label = 'app', model = 'b')
```

[Also you can limit what shows to user in **form level**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291945/how-do-i-filter-foreignkey-choices-in-a-django-modelform)

Comment: The issue is that I can't statically pass a list to `limit_choice_to` bc of the way the child classes of `Solution` are handled.  Thanks, though.

Answer (score 1):

So I arrived here looking for the answer. Based on Mehran's post, I developed the below approach which is similar to yours. Instead the `limit_choice_to` calls a method that returns a runtime created Q object.

Below is the part that is similar to your get_subclasses.

```
def get_subclasses(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    for app_config in apps.get_app_configs():
        for app_model in app_config.get_models():
            model_classes = [c.__name__ for c in inspect.getmro(app_model)]
            if cls.__name__ in model_classes:
                yield app_model
```

This creates the Q filter(s) for us (in my implementation, this is just a plain old method not attached to any class, but I suppose it could be):

```
def get_content_choices():
    query_filter = None

    for cls in Solution.get_subclasses():

        app_label, model = cls._meta.label_lower.split('.')
        current_filter = models.Q(app_label=app_label, model=model)

        if query_filter is None:
            query_filter = current_filter
        else:
            query_filter |= current_filter

    return query_filter
```

And finally, in our model:

```
class ProblemSolutionMapping(models.Model):
    ...
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, limit_choices_to=get_content_choices())
    ...
```