# Reverse access to OneToOne field in an abstract model

Tags: django, database, django-models, one-to-one

Suppose I have the following database structure:

```
class Asset(models.Model):
    # ...

class AbstractBuilding(models.Model):
    asset = models.OneToOneField(Asset, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    # ...

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Office(AbstractBuilding):
    # ...


class Lab(AbstractBuilding):
    # ...


class PowerPlant(AbstractBuilding):
    # ...
```

If I have an `Office` object, it's easy to get the corresponding `Asset` through the one-to-one field (e.g. `office_object.asset` returns an `Asset`). However, suppose I have a `Asset` instead. How can I get the corresponding `Office` (or `Lab` or `PowerPlant`) from the `Asset` object?

Comment: Related: [How do I access the child classes of an object in django without knowing the name of the child class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929029/)

Comment: Related: [Django: Get all implementations of an Abstract Base Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729784/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# You have an instance of Asset e.g.
asset = Asset.objects.first()

office = getattr(asset, "office") # gives you related office if it is related to office

lab = getattr(asset, "lab") # gives you related lab if it is related to lab

power_plant = getattr(asset, "powerplant") # gives you related powerplant if it is related to powerplant
```

Comment: You may want to add an example of catching `django.core.exceptions.ObjectDoesNotExist` if the `getattr` fails to get the specified related object.

Comment: Or even better: `office = getattr(asset, Office.__name__.lower())`. This avoids having to fiddle with strings.