# Is it possible to connect different Product-objects to one Contract?

Tags: python, django, django-models, application-design

**My problem**:
I want my Customers to be able to connect many different Products to one Contract, and the code to list all Products attached to a Contract feels dirty.

**My Models**

```
class Contract(models.Model):
    # The contract, a customer can have many contracts
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)


class Product(models.Model):
    # A contract can have many different products
    contract = models.ForeignKey(Contract)
    start_fee = models.PositiveIntegerField()

# A customer may have ordered a Car, a Book and a HouseCleaning, 
# 3 completly different Products

class Car(Product):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class Book(Product):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)

class HouseCleaning(Product):
    address = models.TextField()
```

To list all the products connected to a Contract, the code looks something like this:

```
c = Contract.objects.get(pk=1)
for product in c.product_set.all():
    print product.book # Will raise an Exception if this product isnt a Book
```

I can't find any sane way to find out what kind of product a Product is!

**My current solution**
I've solved it like this... but this whole mess feels... wrong. I'd be happy for any pointers in the right direction.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    # (as above + this method)

    def getit(self):
        current_module = sys.modules[__name__]
        classes = [ obj for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(current_module)
                    if inspect.isclass(obj) and Product in obj.__bases__ ]

        for prodclass in classes:
            classname = prodclass.__name__.lower()
            if hasattr(self, classname):
                return getattr(self, classname)

        raise Exception("No subproduct attached to Product")
```

So i can fetch each specific product like this (pseudo-ish code)  :

```
c = Contract.objects.get(pk=1)
for product in c.product_set.all():
    print product.getit()
```

to list all the "real" products, and not just the baseproduct instance.

**What I need help with**
Sugggestions to do this in some kind of sane way.
I don't mind having to abstract everything away a bunch of steps, just to get cleaner code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This other stack question looks directly related -- maybe it will help?

```
>>> Product.objects.all()
[<SimpleProduct: ...>, <OtherProduct: ...>, <BlueProduct: ...>, ...]
```

[Subclassed django models with integrated querysets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542157/subclassed-django-models-with-integrated-querysets)

Specifically, the snippet has subclassed models `Meal` `Salad(Meal)`

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1034/

Good luck!

Comment: This was exactly right! :) Thanks!! And today I learned about the contenttypes framework, again: many thanks!

Comment: Hey congrats! I'm super curious about the solution -- did you use the snippet verbatim? Care to share? :D

Answer (score 0):

If you know that a customer's never going to order a `Product`, why not make it an abstract model and then just do the sorting yourself? Accessing a user's books, cars, or house cleanings becomes easy at that point, because you can just use `c.book_set.all()`, `c.car_set.all()`, and so on.

You'd have to do the sorting yourself if you wanted, say, a list of all `Product`s attached to a contract - but it's not hard to write a `sorted` wrapper to put everything into a list for you if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: How Contract will contain Book,Car and HouseCleaning objects which are different from each other?

Comment: Easy: `def product_set(self):  products = self.book_set.all() + self.car_set.all() + self.housecleaning_set.all()  return sorted(products, lambda i: i.created_date)`

Comment: So every time I add a new product, I have to add another c.newproduct_set.all() ? Im not comfortable with that solution... Am i too picky? :)

Comment: Well, ultimately it's up to you - that's how I'd do it, but you're free to do what you'd like. You might want to look into how Django models track their related items - it's possible you could do some introspection to handle the c.newproduct_set.all() part for you.