# How to call a superclass method and return the subclass implementation?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have this models:

```
from django.db import models

class Item(models.Model):
    # ...

    def __str__(self):
        return 'item'

class SubItemA(Item):
    # ...

    def __str__(self):
        return 'subitem_a'

class SubItemB(Item):
    # ...

    def __str__(self):
        return 'subitem_b'
```

And I want to call the **__str__** method from each Item in Item.object.all() and return each subclass implementation, but it only return the superclass implementation.

Example:

```
for item in Item.object.all():
    print(item.__str__())
```

On my database I have two SubItemA and two SubItemB. Than it returns:

```
item
item
item
item
```

I would like to have some thing like this:

```
subitem_a
subitem_a
subitem_b
subitem_b
```

I am lost here.

Comment: with this you will be stumbling upon more problems. A clean solution without reinventing a wheel is to use something like Django Polymorphic https://github.com/chrisglass/django_polymorphic

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko Thank you! It solved my problem like a charm! Please, write a answer so I can vote for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this you will be stumbling upon more problems. A clean solution without reinventing a wheel is to use something like [Django Polymorphic](https://github.com/chrisglass/django_polymorphic)

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit involved.   You might look at [Django model subclassing: Get the subclass by querying the superclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109461/django-model-subclassing-get-the-subclass-by-querying-the-superclass) for a full discussion.

Short answer, from that question:

```
def related_object(self, default_pointer_name='_ptr'):
    models = [A,B] #models
    object = None

    argument = '%s%s' %(self.__class__.__name__.lower(), default_pointer_name)
    query = { argument : self}

    for model in models:
        try:
            object = model.objects.get(**query)
        except model.DoesNotExist:
            pass
        else:
            return object

    if object == None:
        raise RelatedObjectException
    return object

# This is a method used by BaseMedium.
```