# Fetching inherited model objects in django

Tags: python, django, inheritance, model

I have a django application with the following model:

Object **A** is a simple object extending from Model with a few fields, and let's say, a particular one is a char field called **"NAME"** and an Integer field called **"ORDER"**. **A** is abstract, meaning there are no **A** objects in the database, but instead...

Objects **B** and **C** are specializations of **A**, meaning they inherit from **A** and they add some other fields.

Now suppose I need all the objects whose field **NAME** start with the letter *"Z"*, ordered by the **ORDER** field, but I want all the **B** and **C**-specific fields too for those objects. Now I see 2 approaches:

a) Do the queries individually for **B** and **C** objects and fetch two lists, merge them, order manually and work with that.

b) Query **A** objects for names starting with *"Z"* ordered by **"ORDER"** and with the result query the **B** and **C** objects to bring all the remaining data.

Both approaches sound highly inefficient, in the first one I have to order them myself, in the second one I have to query the database multiple times.

Is there a magical way I'm missing to fetch all **B** and **C** objects, ordered in one single method? Or at least a more efficient way to do this than the both mentioned?

Thanks in Advance!

Bruno

Comment: Welcome to Django model inheritance. Enjoy(!) your stay.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `A` can be concrete, you can do this all in one query using `select_related`.

```
from django.db import connection
q = A.objects.filter(NAME__istartswith='z').order_by('ORDER').select_related('b', 'c')
for obj in q:
   obj = obj.b or obj.c or obj
   print repr(obj), obj.__dict__ # (to prove the subclass-specific attributes exist)
print "query count:", len(connection.queries)
```

Comment: Clever. Horrible, but clever. Won't work when A is abstract though?

Comment: Correct, concrete multi-table inheritance only.

Comment: I agree with Wogan, conceptually it's quite ugly, but it works like a charm providing we can make A concrete, which is not such a terrible thing to do in my case! Very Clever!

Answer (score 1):

Querying using your "b" method, will allow for you to "bring in" all the remaining data without querying your B and C models separately. You can use the "dot lowercase model name" relation.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance

```
for object in A.objects.filter(NAME__istartswith='z').order_by('ORDER'):
    if object.b:
        // do something
        pass
    elif object.c:
        // do something
        pass
```

You may need to try and except DoesNotExist exceptions. I'm a bit rusty with my django. Good Luck.

Comment: Yes, you would need to catch `DoesNotExist`, and each attempt to access a related object (successful or not) will cost you an additional query -- terribly inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/929982/1378264).

Use the [InheritanceManager](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager) from the [django-model-utils](https://github.com/carljm/django-model-utils) project.

Answer (score 0):

So long as you order both queries on B and C, it is fairly easy to merge them without having to do an expensive resort:

```
# first define a couple of helper functions 

def next_or(iterable, other):
    try:
        return iterable.next(), None
    except StopIteration:
        return None, other

def merge(x,y,func=lambda a,b: a<=b):
    ''' merges a pair of sorted iterables '''
    xs = iter(x)
    ys = iter(y)
    a,r = next_or(xs,ys)
    b,r = next_or(ys,xs)
    while r is None:
        if func(a,b):
            yield a
            a,r = next_or(xs,ys)
        else:
            yield b
            b,r = next_or(ys,xs)
    else:
        if a is not None:
            yield a
        else:
            yield b
    for o in r:
        yield o

# now get your objects & then merge them

b_qs = B.objects.filter(NAME__startswith='Z').order_by('ORDER')
c_qs = C.objects.filter(NAME__startswith='Z').order_by('ORDER')

for obj in merge(b_qs,c_qs,lambda a,b: a.ORDER <= b.ORDER):
    print repr(obj), obj.__dict__
```

The advantage of this technique is it works with an abstract base class.