# Determining Django Model Instance Types after a Query on a Base-class

Tags: django, inheritance, django-models, django-inheritance

Is there a way to determine what the 'real' class of a Django database object is, after it has been returned from a query for on a base class?

For instance, if I have these models...

```
class Animal(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Person(Animal):
    pants_size = models.IntegerField(null=True)

class Dog(Animal):
    panting_rate = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

And create these instances...

```
Person(name='Dave').save()
Dog(name='Mr. Rufflesworth').save()
```

If I do a query like `Animal.objects.all()`, I end up with two `Animal` instances, not an instance of `Person` and an instance of `Dog`. Is there any way to determine which instance is of which type?

---

FYI: I already tried doing this...

```
isinstance(Animal.objects.get(name='Dave'),Person) # <-- Returns false!
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Welcome to Dja... oh screw it. Here it is, plain and simple. Django model inheritance is broken, and can't be fixed without a lot of work.

Comment: Errr, oh dear, that's not exactly the answer I was hoping for. Does that mean a lot of work from the guys at the Django Project, or does that mean a lot of work by me to hack around the issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had a similar problem in the past and eventually found a *satisfactory* solution thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929029/how-do-i-access-the-child-classes-of-an-object-in-django-without-knowing-the-name/929982#929982).

By implementing an abstract class that stores the *real* class and have it inherited by your parent class, once can cast each parent class instance to the actual type. *(The abstract class used in that answer is now available in [django-model-utils](https://github.com/carljm/django-model-utils/blob/master/model_utils/models.py#L14).)*

For example, once you have the abstract class defined (or if you have django-model-utils), you can simply do:

```
class Animal(InheritanceCastModel):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Person(Animal):
    pants_size = models.IntegerField(null=True)

class Dog(Animal):
    panting_rate = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

Using it is trivial:

```
>>> from zoo.models import Animal, Person, Dog
>>> Animal(name='Malcolm').save()
>>> Person(name='Dave').save()
>>> Dog(name='Mr. Rufflesworth').save()
>>> for obj in Animal.objects.all():
...     print obj.name, type(obj.cast())
...
Malcolm <class 'zoo.models.Animal'>
Dave <class 'zoo.models.Person'>
Mr. Rufflesworth <class 'zoo.models.Dog'>
```

Comment: Looks like I'm going to be going with django-model-utils' InheritanceCastModel. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Unless you're using Django < 1.2, you should not use `InheritanceCastModel` -- see comment on my answer.

Answer (score 18):

We implemented our own cast() function that works quite well (Without ContentType's):

```
class Base(models.Model):
    """
    If your class needs the basics, like created date, modified date etc, then
    inherit from this Base class.
    """
    created = models.DateTimeField(_('Created'), auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(_('Modified'), auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s [%s]' % (self.__class__.__name__, self.id)

    def get_class_name(self):
        return str(self.__class__.__name__).lower()

    def to_json(self, include_related=True):
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'created': self.created.isoformat(),
            'modified': self.modified.isoformat(),
            'class_name': self.__class__.__name__
        }

    def cast(self):
        """
        This method is quite handy, it converts "self" into its correct child class. For example:

        .. code-block:: python

           class Fruit(models.Model):
               name = models.CharField()

           class Apple(Fruit):
               pass

           fruit = Fruit.objects.get(name='Granny Smith')
           apple = fruit.cast()

        :return self: A casted child class of self
        """
        for name in dir(self):
            try:
                attr = getattr(self, name)
                if isinstance(attr, self.__class__):
                    return attr
            except:
                pass
        return self
```

Comment: This will break when a model contains a foreign key to itself. To fix this, use `if isinstance(attr, item.__class__) and type(attr) != type(item):`

Comment: _cast_ method won't work for longer chain of inheritance. For example, if we have `class GreenApple(Apple): ...`, _GreenApple_ won't be detected. The solution is to have a variable `finalattr = attr` in _if_ statement, and than return it afterwards.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, this can be done -- you just need to query the automatic reverse `OneToOneField` relations. E.g.:

```
a = Animal.objects.select_related('person', 'dog')[0]
a = a.person or a.dog or a # whichever is not None
print a
print isinstance(a, Person)
```

The use of `select_related` here allows this to be done in a single query, rather than having to test for `DoesNotExist` exceptions when you access the subclass attributes/relations.

See also my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175009/fetching-inherited-model-objects-in-django/5177641#5177641) and the `InheritanceManager` in [django-model-utils](https://github.com/carljm/django-model-utils/) for a more elegant/long-term solution.

We're looking at ways of making this easier in Django's core.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, for my purposes though I wont actually know ahead of time all the possible class names to try to reference, as such, I'll need to use django-model-utils.

Comment: That's why I recommended it for the long-term. Note however that you're better of the `InheritanceManager` I mentioned above than `InheritanceCastModel` as suggested in your accepted answer, unless you're using a version of Django older than 1.2 -- `InheritanceCastModel` is less convenient and less efficient.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this, consider using [django-polymorphic](https://github.com/chrisglass/django_polymorphic). It supports automatic downcasting of inherited models, works with ForeignKeys/ManyToMany fields and integrates in the admin too.