# Django - Paginating over n tables sorted values

Tags: django, sorting

I've set up a little history audit trail ([django-simple-history](https://bitbucket.org/q/django-simple-history/src)) for a few of my key models and an admin view to [paginate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/?from=olddocs) the (aggregated) entries which are sorted by descending date. The problem is, the method I'm using is suboptimal...

```
historical_foo = Foo.history.all()
historical_bar = Bar.history.all()
historical_qux = Qux.history.all()

#sort the aggregate by modified date
result_list = sorted(chain(historical_foo, historical_bar, historical_qux), key=attrgetter('history_date'), reverse=True)

paginator = Paginator(result_list, 100)

try:
    result = paginator.page(page_num)
    #...
```

This surely won't scale well as this these tables gets large. Is there a way to push the aggregating and sorting logic down into Django / DB or an alternative approach for the same outcome?

Answer (score 2):

You could hold everything in one table with `contenttypes`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic

class HistoryRecord(models.Model):
    history_date = models.DateTimeField()
    history_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    content = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'history_id')
```

then you would need to create those:

```
poll = Poll.history.all()[0]
record = HistoryRecord(content=poll, history_date=poll.history_date)
record.save()
```

or you could subclass `HistoricalRecords`:

```
class IndexedHistoricalRecords(HistoricalRecords):
    def create_historical_record(self, instance, type):
        history_user = getattr(instance, '_history_user', None)
        manager = getattr(instance, self.manager_name)
        attrs = {}
        for field in instance._meta.fields:
            attrs[field.attname] = getattr(instance, field.attname)
        content = manager.create(history_type=type, history_user=history_user, **attrs)
        record = HistoryRecord(content=poll, history_date=poll.history_date)
        record.save()
```

then you can query one table:

```
result_list = HistoryRecord.objects.all()
paginator = Paginator(result_list, 100)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

All models could inherit from one table (via `one-to-one` key).

That way you can sort by django ORM on this field using base table and later on get proper instances.

See [that discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225556/determining-django-model-instance-types-after-a-query-on-a-base-class) for help with getting final instances.