# get sub class type from abstract base class in django

Tags: django, django-models, abstract-class

I have an abstract class called Notification.  I have 2 concrete implementations which are NearNotification and FarNotification.

Each has a different entity associated with them. One is a Department and one is a Group.

I want to send an email to an email associated with either a Department for a NearNotification or a Group for FarNotifications.

Right now my abstract Notification class looks like:

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def send(self):
        group_email = self.group.email
        department_email = self.department.email
```

Depending on which class is created, Department or Group the department or Group field is populated.

**How can I conditionally sort on this subclass to determine which email to use?**

Something like

```
def send(self):
     if concrete class = FarNotification:
          group_email = self.group.email
     elif if concrete class = NearNotification: 
          department_email = self.department.email
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225556/determining-django-model-instance-types-after-a-query-on-a-base-class) question will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access to the name of the class with `self`:

```
def send(self):
     if self.__class__.__name__ = "FarNotification":
          group_email = self.group.email
     elif if self.__class__.__name__ = "NearNotification": 
          department_email = self.department.email
```