# Django - Foreign key from abstract base class

Tags: python, django, inheritance, model

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Polymorphism in Django models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360995/polymorphism-in-django-models)

I have a Constraint abstract base model which has a foreign key to a Group.  Several models inherit from Constraint to behave in a variety of different ways.  Here's a (much simplified) version of what I have:

```
class Constraint(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)

    def get_constraint_type(self):
        return 'Base'

    class meta:
        abstract = True

class UserConstraint(Constraint):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def get_constraint_type(self):
        return 'User'

class ProjectConstraint(Constraint):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)

    def get_constraint_type(self):
        return 'Project'
```

I need to be able to, given a Group, come up with a list of constraint model instances pointing to it.

e.g. if I do

```
group = ...
constraints = group.constraint_set.all()
for c in constraints:
    print c.get_constrait_type()
```

right now, it will print 'Base' a bunch of times, rather than 'User', 'Project', 'User', etc.

A really hacky solution would be to implement a function like this in the base class:

```
def get_child(self):
    try:
        return self.usercontraint
    except UserConstraint.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    try:
        return self.projectcontraint
    except ProjectConstraint.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    # etc...
```

but that seems really terrible.  Do any better solutions exist?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360995/polymorphism-in-django-models

Answer (score 2):

SO, do you mean that you have instance of Group model and you want to have related queryset to UserConstraint or to ProjectConstraint?

There is solution to achieve this with appropriate `related_name` parameter in ForeignKey field. Details are available in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name).

I think you should define Constraint model like this:

```
class Constraint(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name="%(class)s_set")

    def get_constraint_type(self):
        return 'Base'

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

and use it like this:

```
user_constraints = group.userconstraint_set.all()
project_constraints = group.projectconstraint_set.all()
```

**Edit:**

I have changed the `related_name` from `"%(class)s"` to `"%(class)s_set"`. The previous value was not working and I don't know why.

Comment: I want to be able to query all the constraints at once.  e.g. group.<all constraints>() should return both user and project constraints.  From there, I'll have the same function names within each subclass, so calling c.get_constraint_type() will work regardless of which subclass it's in.

Comment: Under the hood there have to be two queries into database so it will be difficult to do it with one queryset. If you have a bunch of subclasses, maybe good option is to introspect Constraint to get subclasses with `Constraint.__subclasses__()` method and generate a list of querysets to join.

Comment: If you want plural for the related_name, you need to add an extra s at the end: "%(class)ss".