# Model inheritance - How can I use overridden methods?

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following code:

```
   # apps/models.py :

class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)

    def __unicode__(self):
        clist = ", ".join([x.__unicode__() for x in self.children.all()])
        return self.name + clist

class Child(models.Model):  
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name='children')
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=80)

    def __unicode__(self):
         return self.desc

class ChildA(Child):
    text = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
         return self.text[:40]
```

I have several items of type `ChildA`. Why when I ask for a `__unicode__()` of the relevant `Parent`, the string I get in return is the one generated by the `__unicode__()` method of `Child` and not the `__unicode__()` method of `ChildA` ?

**Updates:**

This is standard behavior. Another possible solutions in addition to answers below is an [inheritance cast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/929982/416947)

Comment: Please show some evidence that you are doing what you think you are doing.

Comment: **If you've just started developing with Django, I'd recommend you to refrain from using [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance). Consider using simpler and less bug-prone approaches. [Abstract base classes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) will suit you well.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is standard behavior for inheritance. `Parent` is related directly with `Child`, not `ChildA`. When you call `some_parent.children.all()`, you get back a queryset of `Child` instances, so obviously, when you call `unicode` on one of those, it's calling `Child.__unicode__`.

**UPDATE**

There's not really a good way to get from a parent to the child. If you're using MTI (Multiple Table Inheritance), you can take advantage of the way Django implements it, namely as a `OneToOneField` with the parent. Because of that, there's also a reverse relationship on the parent to the child, but you must specifically test for it. For example:

```
class Child(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_child(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'childa'):
            return self.childa
        if hasattr(self, 'childb'):
            return self.childb
        ...
```

It's not ideal by any means, and you need to be careful to always update this method whenever you subclass `Child`, which pretty much totally violates abstraction in OOP.

Comment: Cool. So at least I know it's not something I missed. What are possible workarounds for this behavior so I can access the correct sub-class methods for `some_parent.children.all()`?

Comment: Nice ! You could also add an "assert False" statement at the bottom of the get_child() method, to get some evidence at run-time that some derived class is missing in the list

Answer (score 0):

You probably want an abstract base class.

Read up on the difference here...
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

Comment: I can't use an abstract class because I need the `related_name` functionality and I need to use it with a single name (`children` in my example).

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name

Answer (score 0):

> Why when I ask for a **unicode**() of the relevant parent the string I
>   get in return is the one generated by the **unicode**() method of
>   Child ?

It follows that you are not calling the method on a `Parent` instance. That is why you are seeing this behaviour.

Comment: I am calling the method on a `Parent`. The `Parent.__unicode__()` method cycles through the `__unicode__()` methods of all the children but it's the original method and not the overridden version.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/fjU62hMa
It seems like the system refers to the inheriting models like a parent model. @Marcin

Comment: @Ohad Please put the output and code in your question, edited down appropriately. In any case, I do not see that this shows that you are receiving the results of the sub-instance unicode methods.

Comment: I'm not sure it is necessary in order to replicate the situation I'm describing, but I will try to make it more concise and edit it in later because maybe I'm missing something. Thanks.

Comment: Well, there's a difference between lying and overlooking something that may be the key to the solution which is probably what you're implicating I'm doing. Thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: @Ohad: I don't think you're lying, but I do think that you are incorrect, and there is no reason to believe otherwise. No-one can help you if you insist on ignoring what is actually happening.

Comment: Turns out I was not incorrect. Thanks for motivating me to figure that out.

Comment: @Ohad Where's the evidence? The answer you accepted (from Chris Pratt) agrees with my analysis.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Chris said it is standard behavior, which is correct, and you said I was calling the method on the wrong instance, which is incorrect or at the very least incomplete.

Comment: @Ohad Not really. You are calling it on a different type of object than you thought, which accounts for the entire issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the parent class's method by using the `super()` keyword:

```
a = ChildA()

#This will give you the normal method:
print unicode(a)

#super() will give you the parent's method:
super(ChildA, a).__unicode__()
```

You cannot simply use the `unicode()` function with the latter call, as `super` returns a proxy to the object, rather than an object in its own right.

This is not a good way to code.  Leave it up to the class to override behaviour as it sees fit.