# django multi-table inheritance, access method from child from instance of parent

Tags: django, inheritance, django-models, multi-table-inheritance

I am using Multi-Table inheritance (aka Concrete Inheritance), where I have a non-abstract model + DB Table called Clients, which is concerned with common details concerning all the clients.

But a client can be an Individual, Partnership or Company, for which I have created inheriting models and tables. An Individual has first name + last name, and company has other specific particulars, etc.

I want to be able to access the names of clients (derived from the columns from the child tables) when I want a list of all clients.

After lot of searching, I found that [this tutorial](http://blog.headspin.com/?p=474), works successfully.

Basically, it involves inserting a column on the Client table, which will store the name of the Child model. Then using that name, the appropriate child model is identified and appropriate child method is accessed.

But it seems to be a slightly cumbersome way to implement polymorphism in Multi-Table inheritance.

I want to know whether since 2012, Django has introduced any better way to deal with the issue, or is this still the only way?

***Please let me know if my code sample is required, but the link provided has a beautiful example already.***

Answer (score 3):

There is `django-model-utils` application with [Inheritance Manager](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager). It will cast automatically your parent class to children instances. Example from docs:

```
from model_utils.managers import InheritanceManager

class Place(models.Model):
    # ...
    objects = InheritanceManager()

class Restaurant(Place):
    # ...

class Bar(Place):
    # ...

nearby_places = Place.objects.filter(location='here').select_subclasses()
for place in nearby_places:
    # "place" will automatically be an instance of Place, Restaurant, or Bar
```

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/929029/3606603) question for generic solution with `ContentType`.
And also check awesome [article](https://jeffelmore.org/2010/11/11/automatic-downcasting-of-inherited-models-in-django/) by Jeff Elmore about this topic. Quite old, but still great.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to understand all this and post a reply soon. Thanks again :)

Comment: No, actually I couldn't get it to work. Plus I think as the data grows, the performance degradation will be visible. Can I email you the code maybe?